# Rookie questions about json

Tags: php, json, curl, feed

I know this is a really rookie question but would like some understanding off where to start from guys in the know.

Say if i have a website called

> www.example.com

and its a blog website with lots off blog posts.

I would like to setup the website so i can pull data from i via a http request. Take you tube for example.

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?alt=json

if i paste this in the browser i get all the json which is great for me to use and pull from anywhere.

I would like to setup my website so that i can pull feeds in it from any other website through the http.

http://www.example.com/feeds/api/posts?alt=json

so i can then grab the json with jquery etc.

Can someone please give me a quick understanding off technologies that would be used for this.

Can i do this with php i have looked at curl does anyone now a good tutorial to get me rolling. would i be allowing a feed to my database for them to pull info from their? i am a bit confused to how i all work to be honest.

Any help from you guys would be great ;)

Comment: Good tutorial http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options.

### API

This involves creating an interface to your application. Read http://www.gen-x-design.com/archives/create-a-rest-api-with-php/ for details.

### Feed

You essentially create a read-only output of your data in a previously specified format. Read http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-phprss/ for details.

Answer (score 2):

Docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php
http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/php-tutorial/reading-a-remote-file-using-php.aspx
http://is449w.blogspot.com/2010/03/parsing-json-response-with-php.html

In simply way: PHP has functions to work with JSON (encode and decode objects)

an array in json `["a","b","c"]` will become an array in php `{"a","b","c"}` simply by calling

`$myarray = json_decode("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]")`

Grabbing an remote JSON (API) output is thing discussed in second link i posted (reading a remote file using php), you have several options, where `CURL` is probably the most complex and `file_get_contents` most simply

usual steps are

- Get address of remote feed/api (via url attribute or from database)
- Grab the remote URL
- Push contents of remote URL into View (html template file) or
  request it from server via `jQuery ajax` and work with it directly

Please note a rule about insecure cross-domain access
( [Accessing web Service from jQuery - cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697557/accessing-web-service-from-jquery-cross-domain) )

And second note is about implementing security authentication to your API/feed output, if you need it to work privately
[Web API Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2066107/web-api-security)
[PHP API Key Generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448455/php-api-key-generator)
[API Security: how to restrict access by domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171069/api-security-how-to-restrict-access-by-domain)
[Having security in API System | PHP cuRL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188192/having-security-in-api-system-php-curl)

Comment: maybe add a security layer to it ? so that not everyone has access to the content. something like: ?alt=json&secretKey=qjkfsdhfhseghfsjdfgsjdfj and then do some serverside checks.

Comment: depends on how you will use it, but yes, security layer is good, maybe via some session attribute or so, it has to be simple, as far as it looks @user658500 doesn't have appropriate technical knowledge and experience